# Check IF category_description exists

Tags: categories

How I can check if `category_description()` exist? I need to just echo it when it exist..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've answered your own question.

```
if (category_description($category_id)) {
    echo category_description($category_id);
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description

Comment: thanks, because I tested it with short if and not working.

Comment: You can avoid calling the same function twice by assigning it to a variable first, then checking and echoing it. Set `$cat_description = category_description( $category_id );` and check that in the conditional and echo statement to speed up the display.